# Компиляция для windows из под linux с загрузкой динамической библиотеки

Tags: linux, c, windows

Я использую `SDL_CreateThread ( func, name, data );`. В линуксе всё нормально, я загружаю с помощью dlsym функцию и использую ее. Вот как выглядит указатель на функцию. `SDL_Thread *(*SDL_CreateThread) ( SDL_ThreadFunction fn, const char *name, void *data );`. Проблема в том, что когда я компилирую для windows, то получаю такую ошибку

```
main.c:111:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘sdl2.SDL_CreateThread’
  sdl2.SDL_CreateThread ( thread, "wait", NULL );
```

В заголовке написано так.

```
#elif defined(__OS2__)

typedef void (*pfnSDL_CurrentEndThread)(void);
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Thread *SDLCALL
SDL_CreateThread(SDL_ThreadFunction fn, const char *name, void *data,
                 pfnSDL_CurrentBeginThread pfnBeginThread,
                 pfnSDL_CurrentEndThread pfnEndThread);
#if defined(SDL_CreateThread) && SDL_DYNAMIC_API
#undef SDL_CreateThread
#define SDL_CreateThread(fn, name, data) SDL_CreateThread_REAL(fn, name, data, (pfnSDL_CurrentBeginThread)_beginthread, (pfnSDL_CurrentEndThread)_endthread)
#else
#define SDL_CreateThread(fn, name, data) SDL_CreateThread(fn, name, data, (pfnSDL_CurrentBeginThread)_beginthread, (pfnSDL_CurrentEndThread)_endthread)
#endif

#else
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Thread *SDLCALL
SDL_CreateThread(SDL_ThreadFunction fn, const char *name, void *data);

#endif
```

Вообще есть такая функция в начале

```
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Thread *SDLCALL
SDL_CreateThread(SDL_ThreadFunction fn, const char *name, void *data,
                 pfnSDL_CurrentBeginThread pfnBeginThread,
                 pfnSDL_CurrentEndThread pfnEndThread);
```

Но я хочу использовать функцию именно с тремя параметрами. Как то немного запутанно.
Что мне делать? Да, и ещё, не критично я думаю, вот что пишет компилятор, это уже по другому вопросу.

```
init.c:29:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  sdl2.SDL_Init = GetProcAddress ( lib, "SDL_Init" );
```

В указатель всё равно же загружается как надо указатель на функцию, проблем ведь никаких нет, мне же не обязательно приводить к функции?

Comment: Зачем вы ее загружаете dlsym / GetProcAddress? Касательно второго вопроса - там требуется unchecked conversion

Comment: @VTT потому что мне нужно, чтобы libSDL2 загружалась именно из каталоге игры, никакие опции компилятора не помогают. Поэтому использую динамическую загрузку. В линуксе всё работает нормально, но компилятор mingw-w64 ругается.

Comment: Так у вас тут проблема XY... Заметьте, что на Windows поиск библиотек в папке с исполняемым файлом является поведением по-умолчанию.

Comment: Не приносите Windows в нормальную ОС, иными словами не надо делать так, как вы хотите.